# Getting the US Immigration

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, transfer

We are going to USA on Immgiration Visa and we have funds in our NRO account.

If I transfer these funds to my son before I travel to USA, who have to pay taxes, I and my wife are Tax payers in India,
OR
Is there any option that we can transfer these funds to USA after we open US Bank accounts, then what are taxes we have to pay in USA.

Or Government of USA allowed to the new Immigrants to bring the funds to USA then how much, there any taxes we have to pay in USA if we transfer from my NRO accounts to USA.

Answer (score 1):

> we have funds in our NRO account.

Transfer of funds from NRO account to outside India would need you to complete the FEMA [Foreign Exchange Management Act]. The gist is in [Liberalized Remittance scheme.](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10192&Mode=0) A CA certificate under form 15 CA/CB is required essentially stating taxes on this have been paid. The limit is 250,000 USD per year.

> If I transfer these funds to my son before I travel to USA, who have to pay taxes, I and my wife are Tax payers in India

No tax is applicable under current laws.

> Is there any option that we can transfer these funds to USA after we open US Bank accounts, then what are taxes we have to pay in USA

Yes, this maybe a better option as in the first one transfer of funds from your son back to you would have tax event for you son.